# Binning variable with rolling window on xarray

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-xarray

I have an `xarray.Dataset` with temperature data and want to calculate the binned temperature for every element of the array using a rolling-window of 7-days.

I have data in this form:

```py
import xarray as xr

ds = xr.Dataset(
    {'t2m': (['time', 'lat', 'lon'], t2m)},
    coords={
        'lon': lon,
        'lat': lat,
        'time': time,
    }
)
```

And then I use the `rolling()` method and apply a function on each window array:

```py
r = ds.t2m.\
chunk({'time': 10}).\
rolling(time=7)

window_results = []
for label, arr_window in tqdm(r):
    max_temp = arr_window.max(dim=...).values
    min_temp = arr_window.min(dim=...).values
    if not np.isnan(max_temp):
        bins = np.arange(min_temp, max_temp, 2)
        
        buckets = np.digitize(arr_window.isel(time=-1),
                              bins=bins)
        buckets_arr = xr.DataArray(buckets,
                                   dims={
                                       'lat': arr_window.lat.values,
                                       'lon': arr_window.lon.values
                                   })
        buckets_arr = buckets_arr.assign_coords({'time': label})

        window_results.append(buckets_arr)
```

At the end, I get a list of each timestep with a window-calculation of binned arrays:

```py
ds_concat = xr.concat(window_results, dim='time')
ds_concat

>> <xarray.DataArray (time: 18, lat: 10, lon: 10)>
array([[[1, 2, 2, ..., 2, 2, 3],
        [1, 3, 3, ..., 1, 1, 2],
        [2, 3, 2, ..., 1, 2, 3],
        ...,
        [2, 2, 2, ..., 2, 2, 2],
        [2, 2, 2, ..., 1, 2, 2],
        [2, 2, 3, ..., 2, 3, 2]],
...
```

This code is yielding the results I am looking for, but I believe there must be a better alternative to apply this same process either using `apply_ufunc` or `dask`. I am also using a `dask.distributed.Client`, so I am looking for a way to optimize my code to run fast.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I finally figure it out! Hope this can help someone with the same problem.

One of the coolest features of `dask.distributed` is `dask.delayed`. I can re-write the loop above and use a lazy function:

```py
import dask
import xarray as xr

@dask.delayed
def create_bucket_window(arr, label):
    
    max_temp = arr.max(dim=...).values
    min_temp = arr.min(dim=...).values
    
    if not np.isnan(max_temp):
        bins = np.arange(min_temp, max_temp, 2)
        buckets = np.digitize(arr.isel(time=-1),
                              bins=bins)
        buckets_arr = xr.DataArray(buckets,
                                   dims={
                                       'lat': arr.lat.values,
                                       'lon': arr.lon.values
                                   })
        buckets_arr = buckets_arr.assign_coords({'time': label})

        return buckets_arr
```

and then:

```py
window_results = []
for label, arr_window in tqdm(r):
    bucket_array = create_bucket_window(arr=arr_window,
                                        label=label)
    window_results.append(bucket_array)
```

Once I do this, `dask` will lazy-generate this arrays, and will only evaluate them when needed:

```py
dask.compute(*window_results)
```

And there you will have a collection of results!